# Mobile link broken on my phone

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, work-around

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

I'm using a Nokia C5-04.  When I visit the site, it defaults to the non-mobile version of Stackoverflow.  This is problematic in and of itself, but on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102167/mobile-page-seems-really-large-am-i-loading-the-mobile-page-or-the-normal-page) Kevin Montrose said that for my UserAgent, the mobile site isn't served, why I don't know. Anyway, the link on the bottom of the page to access the mobile site uses JavaScript.  While my phone has quite capable JavaScript abilities, for some reason, this link doesn't work.  Why is the link to the mobile site not a standard href instead of using JavaScript onclick? The source of the link is show below as a reference.

```
<a onclick="StackExchange.switchMobile('on', '/')">mobile</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't support Symbian phones on the mobile site.

We're using javascript in the switch because it's a simple way to make the switch to mobile POST based.

It devolves to `$.post(...)`, and if your phone can't handle *that* it probably cannot deal with the entire mobile site either.

Comment: Is there a URL that I can go to in order to switch to mobile? Most sites use mobile.website.com to automatically go to the mobile sites. I would like to try out the mobile version of the site on my phone, as the full site is quite heavy, but alas there is no way to get there. My phone might not be able to get the full experience on the mobile site, but I imagine it should at least have read capabilities.

Comment: @Kibbee - no there isn't, and there won't be.  If you really want it, find out how to spoof your user-agent.

Comment: Symbian can handle `$.post` just fine now. Can we get Symbian support, please?

Answer (score 0):

I created a page with the following on my website (left out unnecessary stuff, this goes in the body of the document), and placed it on my website.  I can now visit this page, and I have the ability to switch between the mobile and full site. Posting this form basically gets Stackoverflow to send you the cookie for enabling or disabling mobile.  Also, the mobile version works fine on my phone. I've already answered a question using my phone.  In case anybody else wants to enable the cookie, you can use the URL on my site.  [Stackoverflow Mobile Switcher](http://www.kibbee.ca/somobile.html)

```
<form method="POST" action="http://stackoverflow.com/mobile/on">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Turn On Mobile Version">
</form>
<form method="POST" action="http://stackoverflow.com/mobile/off">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Turn Off Mobile Version">
</form>
```